# Is it possible to show QWidget in Java Applet?

Tags: java, qt, applet

I have requirement to open QWidget in Java applet. So when applet gets loaded it should show QWidget within applet and not AS AN INDEPENDENT window. Let me know whether it is possible or not and if possible then how to achieve it. I can open QWidget when applet get loaded but QWidget gets opened as separate window. Let me know your inputs/suggestions on this.

Comment: Did you mean `QWidget` of Nokia?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO. 
The longer answer is NO unless somebody developed a QT container in java. I personally do not believe that someone want to do this: this is like bringing obsolete and old technology to our days.

Comment: and which part of the problem do you mean 'obsolete'? ;) neither Qt nor Java is, actually..